# ExternalAccessory - tutorial - how to - Simulators

Tags: ios, swift, hardware, simulator

would anyone suggest any articles/tutorials how to use this. I would like to be able to "read/decode" data that are sent over the cable into the device. I am aware of the fact, that the device must be certified by apple. But is there a way to "simulate" such device in Xcode for example only to practice writing the code.

Thanks in advance.
Libor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Hardware IO Tools for xcode from following link:

[Hardware IO Tools For Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=for%20Xcode)

I don't know what kind of External Accessory you are using. But on this Tools you will found HomeKit Accessory Simulator, Printer Simulator, Network Link Conditioner, Packet Logger, Bluetooth Explorer etc.

Please comment if you need further help.